# Passing Value of Post ID in Hidden Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This goes along with my other question; trying to get the correct post_id to go along when I submit a new Comment that belongs that a specific Post.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => params[:id] %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => params[:id].post_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kind of hard to know exactly what you are doing without seeing more code, but my guess is that a @post instance variable has set using `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` in the controller

```
# this is not needed, on the create, get it from the post?
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => params[:id] %>
# if you do want to pass it, guessing something like this
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @post.project_id %>

# pass the post id to the create action
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
# if the comment has a project_id
# @comment.project = @post.project ?

# do not send this in hidden field, get the value in your controller
# otherwise the user can change this value to another user when submitting the form
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

you might also want to consider using nested routes in the case of comments?

I recommend reading about view helpers from the rails guides: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html

the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html page actually has code examples for a post with comments

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the security flaws of this. Am going to go research it now and put those values inside the controller so it can't be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to simply put the from from the partial back into the actual view file, and use

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => params[:id].post_id %>
```

However, as house9 pointed out; this is a huge security flaw to use hidden fields to pass values in a form. So changing it around.

Comment: For the other code, please see my previous question posted before this.