# Pass value from jquery to rails form's hidden_field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have jquery which renders a value inside an html element

```
<div id="serialsNewFormatted"></div>
```

Which is nothing but a number/integer. Now I want to pass value rendere inside the above code into my form's `hidden_field`.

How do I do it?

Thanks

UPDATE:  I need to pass the value inside the rails form hidden field, something like `<%= f.hidden_field :data, :value => ValueGoesHere %>`

Comment: This might help: [Passing-value-in-hidden-field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542375/passing-value-of-post-id-in-hidden-field)

Comment: Keep in mind `<%=f.hidden_field ... %>` just renders into html on the server side (when included in a template). So the question you are really asking is "Can I insert html that contains server side variables into div serialsNewFormatted using jquery?". Since jquery is done on the client side, the only way to get access to the variable would be via an ajax request or passing data to your javascript/jquery functions.

Answer (score 1):

Assume

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenObject"/>
```

then

you need below code

```
 $("#hiddenObject").val($("#serialsNewFormatted").html());
```

Comment: Well i already have it in html. i need to pass that as a value inside the rails form hidden field `<%= f.hidden_field :data, :value => ValueGoesHere %>
`